# How to pass two parameters (header text of the clicked cell) and another databound value in query string is asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Based on the cell clicked in the gridview, need to pass the parameter of which column have clicked and its execution id to another page where there is an another grid to display the content based on its parameter.

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="PASS" HeaderText="PASS" 
                SortExpression="PASS" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FAIL" HeaderText="FAIL" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="FAIL" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="yettoexecute" HeaderText="yettoexecute" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="yettoexecute" />
                  <asp:HyperLinkField 
            DataNavigateUrlFields="Executionid,pass" 
                DataNavigateUrlFormatString="TestResultSummary.aspx?Executionid={0}&pass={1}"
                HeaderText="Executionid" 
                DataTextField="Executionid"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "which column have clicked"? The column's index?

Comment: I mean if i clicked the value in a cell, it should pass the value and the name of the column header it belongs to. for example the value is 4 in the pass column, if i click the value 4, i am able to parameterize the value 4 in the query string. but i need the header text of that column "Pass" in the query string.